# The number of vectors it takes to span a finite vector space is equal to the largest number of linearly independent elements of that space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How does one prove that the number of vectors it takes to span a finite vector space is equal to the largest number of linearly independent elements of that vector space?

In other words, why is the size of a basis equal to the largest number of linearly independent elements of a vector space?

---

Context. The definition I use is that a basis $B$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ that spans $V$. I am using the answer to my question to get to to the definition of a basis, not the other way around, so no it isn't obvious. Why does the largest possible amount of linearly independent elements span a finite vector space?

Comment: What is the definition of basis? If you write it down the answer should be obvious!

Comment: A basis B of a vector space V over a field F is a linearly independent subset of V that spans V. I am using the answer to my question to get to to the definition of a basis, not the other way around, so no it isn't obvious.
Why does the largest possible amount of linearly independent elements span a finite vector space?

Comment: Have you heard of Steinitz's exchange lemma?

Comment: Yes.

If {v1, ..., vm} is a set of m linearly independent vectors in a vector space V, and {w1, ..., wn} span V then m ≤ n and, possibly after reordering the wi, the set {v1, ..., vm, wm + 1, ..., wn} spans V.

Comment: Okay, and that's exactly the situation of the question. If $A$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, and $B$ is a spanning set of $V$, then $\operatorname{card} A \leqslant \operatorname{card} B$. Now a linearly independent set is maximal if and only if it spans $V$, and a spanning set is minimal if and only if it is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a vector space $V$.

Let us say the size of basis m. If possible let us assume there exists a linearly independent set of vectors $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,\cdots,u_{m+1}\}$ consisting of $m+1$ elements.

Consider $W=Span\{u_1,u_2,u_3,\cdots,u_{m+1}\}$. Obviously, $W\subset V$.

Then, $dim(W)=m+1<dim(V)=m$, but $W$ is a subspace of $V$, which is absurd.

Therefore, the largest number of independent set of vectors possible  is m.

The elements of basis will form a set of $m$ linearly independent set of vectors.

Therefore,the size of a basis equal to the largest number of linearly independent elements of a vector space.